# Get shared friends username from Facebook after share

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to get username from face book after share post on face book wall like this

Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}name={2}&description={3}", appId,Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, "Hi", "Hi"));

i am doing select some friends from share dialog to share a post  so i need to get these friends username after share post on his wall i am using oauth facebook dll

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the share dialog doesn't give that back. And what do you need it for?

Comment: So what is other way to do this because i am doing share post from website and i want to get username of shared friends and insert in database for my poll application for example  i am log in with facebook account from my website so i have access_token and all things but now i want to share a poll with my 2 friends A and B so i need A and B Username to save in database because these are shared friend

Comment: Ok, as I said I'm pretty sure it is impossible